# Hidding TextBox in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text boxes in html which takes value from database based upon that value i want to hide that particular text box i.e if the value is null the text box disappear please help.Searched a lot but still confused as i want that function to run automatically so can't use on-click or on-change method. I have function that check for the value weather that value is null or not then i set that value to the text box. Found a method of changing the type of text box but not working. 
     readonly>

Comment: But `.change()` is automatically, isn't it!?

Comment: Im suspecting my anwser didnt help?

Answer (score 1):

### Hide

You could just do this. Im just setting the visibility to hidden to completely hide it.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <textarea id="myP">This is a textarea.</textarea>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Hide content of textarea</button>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

### Toggle

Now if you want to toggle you just add another function!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <textarea id="myP">This is a textarea.</textarea>

  <button type="button" onclick="hide()">Hide content of textarea</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="show()">Show content of textarea</button>

  <script>
    function hide() {
      document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden"



    }

    function show() {
      document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "visible"
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```